# AlertDialog with two Edits - when press Button ok --> start new Alert

Tags: java, android, this, android-alertdialog, builder

its a very stupid question, but i started program with java for android just a few days ago and i dont know what to do ....

So i want a AlertDialog when u press a Button. This AlertDialog needs 2 Edits. when u press OK it have to calcutale something and show the solution in a new AlertDialog.

thats what i got :

```
  public void btn_own(View view) {

        int a, b, c;      
        final String s;

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Enter range");

            final EditText inputa = new EditText(this);
            final EditText inputb = new EditText(this);
            alert.setView(inputa);
            alert.setView(inputb);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        int aa, bb, cc , e ;
                        aa = new Integer(String.valueOf(inputa));
                        bb = new Integer(String.valueOf(inputb));
                        cc = bb - aa;
                        Random rand = new Random();
                        int d = rand.nextInt(cc);
                        e = d + bb;
                        Integer out = new Integer(e);


                        s = out.toString(); 

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  
                                .setMessage(s)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

    }
```

The last "this" is wrong. i get the Message :

```
Builder(android.content.Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)
```

but i dont know what i can write in instead of 'this'

a other problem is, that the 's' in the line over 'this' is marked.
 `Cannot assign a value to final variable 's'`

Hope u can help me

---

EDIT:

My new Code :

```
public void btn_own(View view) {
    int a, b, c;        // a : untere Grenze , b : obere Grenze


    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Enter range");

        final EditText inputa = new EditText(this);
        final EditText inputb = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(inputa);
        alert.setView(inputb);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    int aa = 0;
                    int bb = 0;
                    int cc = 0;
                    int e = 0;
                    try {
                        aa = Integer.parseInt(inputa.getText().toString());
                    }   catch (NumberFormatException f) {
                        System.out.println("not a number: " + inputa.getText().toString());
                        f.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        bb = Integer.parseInt(inputb.getText().toString());
                    }   catch (NumberFormatException g) {
                        System.out.println("not a number: " + inputb.getText().toString());
                        g.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cc = bb - aa;
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int d = rand.nextInt(cc);
                    e = d + bb;
                    Integer out = new Integer(e);
                    s = out.toString();

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(Decider.this)
                            .setMessage(s)
                            .show();

                }
            });
        alert.show();



}
```

error : 
Ok now it works like : i can enter one number, then i get an other random number. 
but how can i let it work like : i enter a range, and i get a random number ? 
why does it view just one edit ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener in your activity (it is better because you dont create new object so less resources are used and it saves battery)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
         int aa, bb, cc, e;
         aa = new Integer(String.valueOf(inputa));
         bb = new Integer(String.valueOf(inputb));
         cc = bb - aa;
         Random rand = new Random();
         int d = rand.nextInt(cc);
         e = d + bb;
         Integer out = new Integer(e);
         s = out.toString(); 
         new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(s).show();
    }
}
```

Then set your button with this:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be nesting AlertDialogs inside other AlertDialogs.

So this:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  
                        .setMessage(s)
                        .show();
```

Will use the wrong context, but you will have to pass an activity as the context

Try using `YourActivity.this` or `view.getContext()` as param instead

---

**Update:** about your `NumberFormatException` you should try this:

```
 try {
      aa = Integer.parseInt(inputa.getText().toString());
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("not a number: " + inputa.getText().toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

But you need to be sure that your editText only allows numbers!!

Comment: thanks for your update, sry but i had to do some stuff the last hour

so, i edited my code, but i still get Invalid int ... 
and when i press the button, the app breaks down 
(and i still have just one edit ... ) 
nothing want to work like i want .. :D

Comment: @QNikE Let's try again updated code!;-) and for the case it breaks what will be in the logs?

Comment: okk tried it with try/catch

check update 

problem is : aa and bb 'might not been initialized' 
and i still got just one Edit, but i need two ...

Comment: ok, instead of `int aa, bb, cc, e;` assign initial values to your vars, like `int aa == 0;` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `view.getContext()` instead of `this` which refer to the OnClickListener context to create AlertDialog as:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
```

Second if you want to change value on `s` on Alert button click then remove `final` from the `s` and declare it outside `btn_own` method.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an int from String use:

```
aa = Integer.parseInt(inputa.getText()));
```

Surround it with try/catch to avoid user bad input and your exception

Comment: aa = Integer.parseInt(inputa.getText()));

Comment: still the same error

when i press the button, i get a Alert with one Edit , and when i press OK the app breakes down .....